# How to see 6-digit file permissions?

Tags: macos, unix, permission

I have an application that complains about the permissions of its directory inside of /Applications.  It wants to be set to 040775.  I can fix it by running `chmod 040775`, but I do not understand what the first 2 digits mean.  Just running `chmod 775` does not work, so apparently these first 2 digits are wrong.  What are these 2 digits, and how can I view them in macOS?  I'm looking for something like `ls -l`.  I'm running High Sierra.

Comment: I do not believe that `040775` in `chmod 040775` is a valid permissions. I'd suggest you read the `MODES` section of the `man page` for `chmod`. You probably want: `chmod 4775`

Comment: I have read the man page, and it only described 4 digits. I was surprised by this too, but why does the command I wrote solve the problem?

Comment: Without knowing what the permission were before you ran the `chmod` _command_ I can not say specifically, however `04` of `040775` is ignored and `0775` sets the permissions to `rwxrwxr-x` and normal application bundles and normal executable files are usually set to `rwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: The first two digits are the file type and the remaining four are the permission bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is stat and ask for permissions field:

```
stat -f "%p" file
```

That application or instructions or memory is likely wrong. From the manual page, there are 4 digits in the octal representation for modes on macOS:

> ```
>  Modes may be absolute or symbolic.  An absolute mode is an octal number
>  constructed from the sum of one or more of the following values:
>
>        4000    (the set-user-ID-on-execution bit) Executable files with
>                this bit set will run with effective uid set to the uid of
>                the file owner.  Directories with the set-user-id bit set
>                will force all files and sub-directories created in them to
>                be owned by the directory owner and not by the uid of the
>                creating process, if the underlying file system supports
>                this feature: see chmod(2) and the suiddir option to
>                mount(8).
>        2000    (the set-group-ID-on-execution bit) Executable files with
>                this bit set will run with effective gid set to the gid of
>                the file owner.
>        1000    (the sticky bit) See chmod(2) and sticky(8).
>        0400    Allow read by owner.
>        0200    Allow write by owner.
>        0100    For files, allow execution by owner.  For directories,
>                allow the owner to search in the directory.
>        0040    Allow read by group members.
>        0020    Allow write by group members.
>        0010    For files, allow execution by group members.  For directo-
>                ries, allow group members to search in the directory.
>        0004    Allow read by others.
>        0002    Allow write by others.
>        0001    For files, allow execution by others.  For directories
>                allow others to search in the directory.
>
>  For example, the absolute mode that permits read, write and execute by
>  the owner, read and execute by group members, read and execute by others,
>  and no set-uid or set-gid behaviour is 755 (400+200+100+040+010+004+001).
> ```

I've made a file conveniently named 040775 and applied permissions - you can see the 040 clears all sticky (as it’s 0775 part that matters), setUID, setGID bits so you get 0775 if you try to set 040775.

```
mac:foo me$ touch 040775
mac:foo me$ stat -f "%p" 040775 
100644
mac:foo me$ chmod 040775 040775
mac:foo me$ stat -f "%p" 040775 
100775
mac:foo me$ chmod 4775 040775 
mac:foo me$ ls -l
-rwsrwxr-x  1 me  wheel  0 May 10 20:30 040775
mac:foo me$ chmod 040775 040775
mac:foo me$ ls -l
-rwxrwxr-x  1 me  wheel  0 May 10 20:30 040775
```

I've edited the above a bit and didn't do all the `stat` and `ls` but it should help you poke around at existing files and test out whether my experience that only the last 4 digits are interpreted as an octal bit mask to set permissions as documented in the chmod man page.

Comment: You said, "you can see the 040 clears all sticky ..." and I believe you are wrong in that statement and in fact it's the `0` in `0775` that's clears all sticky.  `04` of `040775` is ignored and I say that because if you first set e.g. `4775` and then use `010775`, it does the same as  `040775` does and the `01` of `010775` is ignored just like the `04` of `040775` is ignored and `chmod` just processes it as `0775` in both examples.

Comment: It may be worth noting that these are octal numbers (three bits/digit with a value of 0-7). When I've seen decimal numbers for file permissions, I think Disk Utility does this, converting them to octal gives what I consider reasonable values for permission.

Comment: @user3439894 I’ll clarify the post. Thanks. I agree and intended to relate that the first 0 and first 4 are discarded. It’s the 0 before 775 that does the clearing. In hindsight using 1 would be better than 4 to show that 1 sets and 0 clears.

Comment: It turns out those first two digits are the file mode, which can be seen with `stat -f %p filename`. "04" means it is a directory.  Maybe in this case `chmod 0775` would have the same effect.  But chmod does seem to be somewhat aware of this because `chmod 240775` gives an error, while `chmod 140775` does not. 
https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/2-stat/

Comment: @Elliott: `240775` generates a error because this value can not be stored in a 16 bit integer, where as, `140775` can be stored.